# Why this form is submitting when hitting Enter in a field?

Tags: html, forms, submit, onkeyup

I have this form submitting itself when hitting enter key in the "departments.name_text" field. It shouldn't! I'm returning false after onKeyUp...any comments why this is happening?

```
<form id="departments_form" method="POST" name="departments_form" action="app-forms.php">
    <input id="departments.name_text" placeholder="Department Name" onKeyUp="alert(event.keyCode); return false;">
    <select name="departments.name" id="departments.name" size="6" ondblclick="this.remove(this.selectedIndex);">
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put return statement on code below.

In order to catch return statement you have to put return ondblclick().

```
<select name="departments.name" id="departments.name" size="6" ondblclick="return this.remove(this.selectedIndex);">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using onKeyUp. The onKeyUp trigger after the form is submitted. So that you can not block the submit action by onKeyUp.

You should use the onKeyPress instead of onKeyUp.

```
onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;"
```

However, in some browser it do not support onKeyPress

You can use the jQuery code to prevent the form submit by

```
$(document).on("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
         event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery...any solution using plain vanilla JS?